# JSON web service correct encoding using django

Tags: python, django, json, character-encoding

I'm building a json web service which contains strings with characters like é,ñ,Á,etc.

Using python I found this snippet of code that works perfectly when I run it in console:

```
import json
string = "NIÑO, ÁRBOL, HÉROE"
print json_dumps({'string': string}, ensure_ascii=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

The thing is that I'm using Django, and it doesn't look like it is as straightforward as the code above. Here's a peek of what I'm doing at my views.py file

```
import json
from models import *
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db.models import Q

def jsonService(request):
    # The following line performs a query at the db
    myObjects = MyObjects.objects().filter( Q(...) ) 

    result = {"string": myObject[0].field } # let's say myObject[0].field contains "NIÑO, ÁRBOL, HÉROE"

    # Prepares a response
    response = HttpResponse(json.dumps(result, ensure_ascii=False, encoding="utf-8"))
    # Sets the heades of content type and its charset
    response['Content-type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

    # Returns the response we prepared
    return response
```

The output of this code is:

```
{ 
    string : "NIÃ´O, ÃRBOL, HÃ%ROE"
}
```

if I apply python's function repr() to the string myObject[0].field when I assemble the result object, to my surprise the result is:

```
{ 
    string : "NI\xc3\u2018O, \xc3\x81RBOL, H\xc3\u2030ROE"
}
```

What I can infere from here is that maybe the strings that the db delivers (which are unicode strings acording to python's type()) are encoded in a format other that utf-8, but it thows me the following error:

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 14: ordinal not in range
```

Those escaped characters seems very strange to me, not to mention that I don't want unicode strings but the accented characters (something like {string: "NIÑO, ÁRBOL, HÉROE"}), I know it's possible because I've seen some google services work with accents.

Some advise? maybe I'm doing something incredibly wrong that I haven't realized, that's why I described the full process.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the database is using utf-8?  mySQL does not by default.

Comment: @AgDude I'm not sure how is that. I filled the database with a python script, where i specified when opening the connection the encoding utf-8, and when I uploaded the db to my server, heroku btw, I also specified the same encoding. Will it do or I missed to apply some special config to my dbm?

Comment: I have not used heroku, but check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7615292/4803030).  As always, if you are altering an existing database, make a backup first!

Comment: @AgDude Before modifying heroku's configuration, I query for the current on with `heroku config` and the default value was already `en_US.UTF-8`, I changed to `es_ES.UTF-8` and server restarted automatically, but nothing. I've been researching about this `\xc3\` character, maybe it is the remanent of some previous encoding, but not sure yet.

Comment: It looks like it is coming out of the database already incorrect.  Use a pdb.set_trace() to view the object in the python shell using runserver.  How was the data inserted into the database?  Can you look at the data directly in a SQL client?

Comment: @AgDude Nice tool that of `pdb.set_trace()`, I applied it right after the query and the result was the string `NI\xc3\u2018O, \xc3\x81RBOL, H\xc3\u2030ROE`. So I checked the way I inserted the data and I commit a mistake when inserting rows in the database tables. Here's [_the code_](https://gist.github.com/4334647) **The solution was filling again the database with UTF-8 encoding**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your views.py works fine for me

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

def jsonService(request):

    myObjects = MyObjects.objects().filter( Q(...) )
    fields = [x.field for x in myObjects] # creates a list of all fileds 

    # it will create JSON object
    result=simplejson.dumps({
        'fileds':fileds,
     })

    return HttpResponse(result, mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: if I use this method I get the same result as when using json `{string : "NIÃ´O, ÃRBOL, HÃ%ROE"}`. However I'm afraid that maybe there's something missing, because DjangoJSONEncoder it's not  used, is it? I'm very optimistic about this approach because a workmate advised me to use simplejson too.