# Zurb Foundation checkbox looking funny when publishing live

Tags: forms, checkbox, zurb-foundation

I have a simple Foundation [checkbox according to these docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/custom-forms.html). Looks great locally:
[image]

However, when I publish to Heroku, my checkboxes all look like this, no code was changed: [image]

Any ideas? Here's my code for the checkbox:

```
<label class="inline" for="attendance_shirt">
        <input name="attendance[shirt]" type="hidden" value="0">
        <input id="attendance_shirt" name="attendance[shirt]" style="display: none;" type="checkbox" value="1" class="hidden-field"><span class="custom checkbox checked"></span> Check here
</label>
```

Using the latest Foundation v4.1.6

***UPDATE***: Seems that things work nice locally because the `content` css property of the `span` element representing the checkbox is `"\00d7"`. However, when I publish my Rails site to Heroku, that SCSS code in `_custom-forms.scss` turns into `"\2A2F"` for some reason.

Is this just a bug in the Foundation gem for Rails? Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Zurb docs, the custom checkbox appears to be using UTF-8 Multiplication Symbol × (\00d7 in a css content) instead of a regular X character. If you are using the same character, you may have to configure Heroku to use UTF-8.

Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7615292/773517) answer, this line might help you out:

```
heroku config:add LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: I'm already on UTF-8 encoding in Heroku: (within `heroku run bash`) `irb(main):001:0> "a".encoding (next line) 
"a".encoding (next line) 
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>`