# Why doesn't Heroku specify a default character encoding on their virtual machines?

Tags: encoding, utf-8

It seems that Heroku doesn't explicitly specify a character encoding on their virtual machines, so the default becomes 8-bit ASCII. Other modern versions of Debian and Ubuntu specify UTF-8 as a default, and this avoids problems when languages fall back to operating-system character encoding for reading input. Why wouldn't Heroku use this default as well?

Based on other SO posts, I've found that at least [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612912/set-utf-8-as-default-string-encoding-in-heroku), [SBCL](https://github.com/jsmpereira/heroku-buildpack-cl) and [Haskell application developers](https://github.com/begriffs/heroku-buildpack-ghc/pull/21) have dealt with this problem, and they suggest setting UTF-8 explicitly at the operating system level to avoid problems via the following command:

```
heroku config:add LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

I feel like this is something that Heroku must have considered since character encoding is so important. Is there a good reason for Heroku not to specify UTF-8 as an operating system default?

Comment: https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new?query=contact+heroku

Comment: Thanks @ZekeSonxx. I've already submitted a support request to Heroku, and I'll follow up on this question as well if I get an answer to my query through their official support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku support was extremely helpful in answering my question. Essentially, they just leave the encoding up to the buildpack for each language. Additionally they gave me links to how this is implemented in the buildpacks they maintain for [Python](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/blob/566f7f4555dcde26252a0db01f6bd28f6bb00494/bin/compile#L84) and [Ruby](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/blob/2eb97fcbf5e369800596ba6b070fde0ef17c59e9/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb#L60).

I found the Python script particularly helpful in setting the encoding automatically for Haskell apps (I copied parts of it for the Haskell buildpack). [Here's the PR I created to set UTF-8 as a default in Haskell](https://github.com/begriffs/heroku-buildpack-ghc/pull/22). You should specify the default character encoding in two places in the [compile script in the buildpack API](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api). First, it's probably a good idea to export the language before compiling the compiler itself, as they do for Python. Second (and most importantly for your application) you should set it in the [.profile.d script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/profiled) so that it gets picked up as the context for your application.

Hope this is helpful info to folks making buildpacks for other languages!