# Non-English (Hebrew) characters inserted well to mysql DB, only when jetty app runs on localhost?! (deployed to heroku)

Tags: java, mysql, heroku, jersey, embedded-jetty

I made a Jersey restful service and ran it on tomcat for months (on cloudbees). It ran sweetly - hebrew inserted to mysql-db via service POST methods with no problems.

Recently cloudbees closed their free plan so i had to migrate to jetty - heroku free java plan...

So now everything works fine, except when i insert hebrew characters with one of my service POST methods; its inserted as quotation marks, but only when its already deployed on heroku!
When i'm running the service with jetty on my local machine there is NO PROBLEM - hebrew is inserted just fine.

I'd appreciate any ideas guys...

(I checked utf8 collation on the db, schema, table and columns...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I needed to add this to the Heroku app config Vars:

> heroku config:add LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Source:
[Set UTF-8 as default string encoding in Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612912/set-utf-8-as-default-string-encoding-in-heroku)