# Collation utf8_general_ci is not working on Heroku

Tags: mysql, heroku, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I am using Exposed library by JetBrains with MySQL database connection. In my database I need to use UTF-8 encoding field so I'm using `utf8_general_ci` collation. I tested it on my local database and it works just fine, but when I run the same code on Heroku database I've got question marks instead of UTF-8 symbols. 
Here's my schema object:

```
object UserMessage : Table() {
  val id = varchar("id", 20).primaryKey()
  val channelId = varchar("channel_id", 20)
  val content = varchar("content", 2000, collate = "utf8_general_ci")
  val creatorId = varchar("creator_id", 20).nullable()
  val creationDate = varchar("creation_date", 26)
}
```

Creation script for both databases is the same and looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `usermessage` (
  `id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(2000) NOT NULL,
  `channel_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  `creator_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What should I do to make encoding work on Heroku?

Comment: Heroku doesn't provide a MySQL database service. Which third-party addon are you using?

Comment: I am using ClearDB

Comment: Maybe utf8_general_ci is default collation for utf8 charset?

Comment: I actually found out that the default encoding for string in Heroku is not UTF-8: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7612912/set-utf-8-as-default-string-encoding-in-heroku/7615292. So I changed it and solved my problem.